# Possible duplicates added through multiple accounts

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, user-accounts

I ran across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738574/get-data-from-multiple-table) this morning that looked vaguely familiar so I did some searching and found, two other versions that are identical but are coming from different accounts:

- [how can i use distinct INNER JOIN RFM ON RFM.RFMID=PV.RFMID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688430/how-can-i-use-distinct-inner-join-rfm-on-rfm-rfmid-pv-rfmid)
- [id getting duplicate PV.RFMID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698748/id-getting-duplicate-pv-rfmid)

When I commented on the [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738574/get-data-from-multiple-table) that is was a possible duplicate, the author of the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688430/how-can-i-use-distinct-inner-join-rfm-on-rfm-rfmid-pv-rfmid) quickly edited it to remove the table data and any sign that they were the same.

It kind of seems that the accounts are by the same person:

1. [First Account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1481713/john)
2. [Second Account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487761/njg)

All of the questions were flagged as duplicates but it doesn't seem that this type of behavior is appropriate, they don't get an answer with one account so they then use a second account to post and then edit when found out.

Should the moderators just be flagged in these cases?  Just to determine proper etiquette.

Comment: Homework, perhaps? Multiple students posting the same assignment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters possible but when I first pointed out the duplicate on [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738574/get-data-from-multiple-table) the [second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688430/how-can-i-use-distinct-inner-join-rfm-on-rfm-rfmid-pv-rfmid) was edited to remove any duplicate content.  That is what raised my curiosity to look further.

Comment: If true, then [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225633/how-i-get-last-cell-where-user-ends-dragging/11239838#11239838) from one to the other is certainly sock puppetry.

Comment: @bluefeet: That supports the homework assignment hypothesis just as much, and not wanting to be caught out on looking for answers to your homework on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can flag one of their posts for moderator attention, and explain the situation.

I merged the users.

Comment: However, it might be hard to express the above amount of information in a custom flag, due to the character limitations. This could be a case where a Meta post is a little more helpful, even though flags are  almost always the way to go.

Comment: You've got 500 characters to work with in a flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks for the help, I wasn't sure the best route.